# How do I get rid of these remapping warnings in a brand new MVC project after updating all nuget packages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I've seen a million questions about this but it all seems a little different, I do apologize if this is a dupe though.

I've created a brand new MVC project. I've stripped out a bunch of Nuget packages I'm not using (bundling/optimization, jQuery, bootstrap, etc.).

When I build I get this:

```
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "Newtonsoft.Json, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" from Version "4.5.0.0" [] to Version "9.0.0.0" [...\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "Antlr3.Runtime, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=eb42632606e9261f" from Version "3.4.1.9004" [] to Version "3.5.0.2" [...\packages\Antlr.3.5.0.2\lib\Antlr3.Runtime.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
```

I also get the following in VS error list view:

```
Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file: <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding>
```

I went ahead and double clicked that entry but it does nothing and the error is dismissed (no file content changes). When I build again I get the same warnings again each time.

This is the contents of my `<runtime>` object in my Web.config:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

What am I missing?

NOTE: I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Pro. This is a standard ASP.Net 4.5 MVC template project, not .Net Core.

EDIT: Forgot to mention the Solution Nuget manager "Consolidate" tab is empty for me.

Comment: These are so infuriating, and yet we're still dealing with them. Come on Microsoft, there HAS to be an easier way to fix this sillyness!  `>:|`

Comment: Totally agree with you @ScottK.Fraley but I think MS will sooner abandon MSBuild and Nuget and adopt a new build system before fixing these ever-present issues. Just don't hold your breath friend.